# Docker daemon no start

Tags: docker, systemd

I'm trying to start the Docker daemon:

```
sudo systemctl start docker
```

But nothing happens, the cursor just blinks and the process never ends.

Yesterday it was working properly :(

```
sudo journalctl -fu docker

ago 18 16:05:24 host docker[1602]: time="2016-08-18T16:05:24.467635627-05:00" level=info msg="New containerd process, pid: 1609\n"
ago 18 16:05:24 host docker[1602]: time="2016-08-18T16:05:24.482107319-05:00" level=fatal msg="bad listen address format /var/run/docker/libcontainerd/docker-containerd.sock, expected proto://address"
ago 18 16:05:30 host docker[1602]: time="2016-08-18T16:05:30.470570243-05:00" level=info msg="New containerd process, pid: 1620\n"
ago 18 16:05:30 host docker[1602]: time="2016-08-18T16:05:30.491495106-05:00" level=fatal msg="bad listen address format /var/run/docker/libcontainerd/docker-containerd.sock, expected proto://address"
ago 18 16:08:06 host systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
-- Reboot --
ago 18 16:16:52 host systemd[1]: Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
ago 18 16:16:54 host docker[2294]: time="2016-08-18T16:16:54.360878396-05:00" level=info msg="New containerd process, pid: 2327\n"
ago 18 16:16:54 host docker[2294]: time="2016-08-18T16:16:54.686503187-05:00" level=fatal msg="bad listen address format /var/run/docker/libcontainerd/docker-containerd.sock, expected proto://address"
ago 18 16:17:00 host docker[2294]: time="2016-08-18T16:17:00.664023288-05:00" level=info msg="New containerd process, pid: 2368\n"
ago 18 16:17:00 host docker[2294]: time="2016-08-18T16:17:00.67708602-05:00" level=fatal msg="bad listen address format /var/run/docker/libcontainerd/docker-containerd.sock, expected proto://address"
```

Comment: `sudo journalctl -fu docker`

Comment: Looks like docker restarted and your start CLI just didn't give you a prompt. Did you try a `docker info` to see if you can connect?

Comment: @BMitch this is the solution https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=216046 thanks

Answer (score 0):

One *interesting* thing with systemd is that if it thinks that a daemon is running, then the start command does nothing.

I have had to do the following to make sure I *cleanly* restart certain daemons:

```
sudo systemctl stop service-name

# wait a little if the service is slow to stop like the Cassandra database

sudo systemctl start service-name
```

That has worked for me with various services.

One way to know whether the service is considered running, is to check the status like so:

```
systemctl status service-name
```